# ListView not populated. Problem with ViewPager and fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have three fragments switched using a ViewPager and the third one contains a ListView.

My problem is that the ListView is not populated on the first time that I switch to that fragment. I have to switch back to the first then back to the third again and only will the ListView be populated. What seems to be the problem here?

How does ViewPager works anyways?

Here is my TabAdapter

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}
```

}

Here is ListAdapter for the listView

```
   public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

    public ListAdapter(LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> lhm) {
        try {
            data.addAll(lhm.entrySet());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public LinkedHashMap.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> getItem(int position) {
        return (LinkedHashMap.Entry) data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final LinkedHashMap.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> item = getItem(position);
        final ArrayList quotesList = item.getValue();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.archive_list, parent, false);
        }
        TableRow tableRow = convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ImageView copy = convertView.findViewById(R.id.copy);
        copy.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        title.setText(item.getKey() + " Quotes");

        tableRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", item.getKey());
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("quotes", quotesList);
                if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Update**

The problem seems to be from the Linkedhashmap. I tried manually putting values into the Hashmap and it worked. The problem now is my current code. I populate my hashmap by retrieving data from firebase and that seems to be the problem? Pershaps it isn't populated as quickly?

```
    private void initArchives() {
    DatabaseReference dBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("archive");
    dBase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                DataPojo dp = snapshot.getValue(DataPojo.class);
                hm.put(dp.getName(), dp.getMessages());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_archive, container, false);
    listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);


    initArchives();
    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(hm);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listView.invalidateViews();

    loadAds();

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is really a pain in the ass. But we have to work with that. I suggest you to Ctrl + click on `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and read source code.

Another thing is adding fragments to your `ArrayList` with `addFragment()` method might not be the best idea since `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is saving the states of the fragments and loads them from its own `FragmentManager`.

So the fragment you added might not be the fragment you are getting. 
A possible solution to that would be using tags.

There are some must read articles about the topic [here](https://medium.com/inloopx/adventures-with-fragmentstatepageradapter-4f56a643f8e0) [here](http://speakman.net.nz/blog/2014/02/20/a-bug-in-and-a-fix-for-the-way-fragmentstatepageradapter-handles-fragment-restoration/) and [here](http://billynyh.github.io/blog/2014/03/02/fragment-state-pager-adapter/).

And oh one other thing. `ViewPager` creates three fragments at a time when using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. First it creates fragment to display and next the fragment on the right and last the fragment on the left. Since you have three fragments, the last (3rd) fragment is not created right away (There is no fragment on the left of the first fragment). Maybe you are loading some data that takes time to download on the third fragment? And next time you display the 3rd fragment it loads from the saved state of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. These are just some possibilities to think about. Not necessarily is the right solution. Good luck.